# How to get a vector of n as the output of box muller function in r

Tags: r, statistics

I have written a box muller function. However, my output is of length 2n. How do I get my output to be a vector of length n?

Comment: Am I right that you want the output to be a list of length `n` with each element of that list being a vector with two values, `c(X1, X2)` for that given n?

Comment: Yes. I want to return X1 and X2 but as a vector of length n.

Comment: Just to clarify, the box muller transform returns pairs of points, while a vector is one-dimensional.  If you do n calculations, each returning two values, it must give you 2*n results.  What is the call to `hist` hoping to show?

Comment: Yes. But I am supposed to write a function box_muller with a single argument n, that returns n random variables from N (0, 1). Hist will give me the histogram of the n variables from box muller. You may heed it no mind.

Comment: I'm not sure that entirely makes sense, but see Allan Cameron's helpfully laid out answer for code that does what I think the question setter is asking of you.

Comment: But the question specifies to return a vector of length n not a list?

Comment: Then something has been misunderstood somewhere.  I think the assignment is in error, or our understanding of it may be.

Answer (score 2):

Your function would need to return a list of two vectors, each of length `n`. It would be sensible to call these `x` and `y`:

```r
box_muller <- function(n) {
  U1 <- runif(n)
  U2 <- runif(n)
  X1 <- sqrt(-2*log(U1))*cos(2*pi*U2)
  X2 <- sqrt(-2*log(U1))*sin(2*pi*U2)
  return(list(x = X1, y = X2))
}
```

Now testing it, we can create a list with `x` and `y` components that each should each be independent draws from a standard normal distribution:

```
set.seed(1)

n = 1000

BM <- box_muller(n)
```

We can plot the object directly:

```r
plot(BM)
```

[image]

And confirm the length of its members

```r
length(BM$x)
#> [1] 1000
length(BM$y)
#> [1] 1000
```

It doesn't make sense to plot a histogram of the whole object, but we can draw one for each of its members

```
hist(BM$x)
```

[image]

```r
hist(BM$y)
```

[image]

And we can confirm `x` and `y` are not correlated

```r
cor(BM$x, BM$y)
#> [1] -0.01615875
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hello, I am supposed to draw just one histogram. When I use list, I am unable to plot the histogram as I get Error in hist.default(box_muller(n), freq = FALSE) : 'x' must be numeric. Furthermore, I am supposed to get a vector of length n as the output. But your output is of length 2

Comment: @user19825372 but the whole point of a box-muller is to give you _two_ vectors of length n. That's what X1 and X2 are. If you wanted to, you could just get the function to return X1, then you would get a single normally distributed output of length n and hist`box_muller(n)` would work, (the same as `hist(BM$x)` in my example above). But then why would you calculate X2 in your function at all? Are you _certain_ you understand what the assignment is asking for? It doesn't make a lot of sense to me.